# How to add a column to dataframe based on condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe which has certain columns. I want to add one more column which would be dependent on source column. The dataframe looks like below :

[The year_23 column needs to be added based on source value.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4unVu.png)

Fy_23 is a static value based on the source. I am new to pandas and need some advice on how it can be acheived

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a function like this:

```
def do_this(source):
    if Source == 'Google':
       return "The string you want"
    else:
       return "The string you want if above condition is not satisfied"
```

After that select the column from dataframe on which you want to apply changes and assign it to new column that you want.

```
df['New Column'] = df['Column'].apply(do_this)
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [np.where](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)

```
df["Year_23"] = np.where(df["Source"].eq("Google"), "x", "y")
```

Answer (score 1):

Another simple solution would be to create an empty column and modify the values according to the `Source` column values:

```
df['year_23'] = np.nan
df['year_23'][df['Source']=='Google'] = 'text1'
df['year_23'][df['Source']=='Bing'] = 'text2'
```